# When importing a module in another .py , return of function is different to directly run it?

Tags: python, data-science, python-3.6, object-oriented-analysis

I have the following program:

```
def savings_account(client_to_accounts: Dict[Tuple[str, int],
                     List[List[float]]], valid_client: Tuple[str, int],
                       balance: float, interest: float)-> list:
   ''' Return the newest update of accounts added.'''

   key_list = client_to_accounts.keys()
   for i in key_list:
       if i == valid_client:
           last = len(client_to_accounts[i][0]) - 1
           client_to_accounts[i][0].insert(last,balance)
           client_to_accounts[i][1].insert(last,interest)

   return client_to_accounts[i]
```

When I call this func from original file like to:

```
actual = savings_account({('Habib', 696969696): [[1.0, 10000.0], [2.0, 1.0]],
                              ('Hendiye', 123456789): [[20000.0, -100.0], [1.0, 1.0]]},
                              ('Hendiye', 123456789),40.0, 2.0)
print(actual)
#printed: [[20000.0, 40.0, -100.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

the value of `('Hendiye', 123456789)` correctly will be update. but when call this function from other python file the value of `('Hendiye', 123456789)` isn't updated.

```
 import banking_functions
 param1 = {('Habib', 696969696): [[1.0, 10000.0], [2.0, 1.0]], ('Hendiye', 123456789): [[20000.0, 
        -100.0], [1.0, 1.0]]}
 param2 = (('Hendiye', 123456789),40.0, 2.0)
 param3 =  40.0
 param4 =   2.0
                    
 actual = banking_functions.savings_account(param1, param2, param3, param4)
 #expected = [[20000.0, 40.0, -100.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
 print(actual)
 #printed : [[20000.0, -100.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. Also, use more descriptive names than `param1`, `param2`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second snippet does not call the function in the same way the first does.

Did you mean:

```py
import banking_functions

param1 = {('Habib', 696969696): [[1.0, 10000.0], [2.0, 1.0]], ('Hendiye', 123456789): [[20000.0, 
        -100.0], [1.0, 1.0]]}
param2 = ('Hendiye', 123456789)  # Just a tuple of two items
param3 =  40.0
param4 =   2.0
                    
actual = banking_functions.savings_account(param1, param2, param3, param4)
#expected = [[20000.0, 40.0, -100.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
print(actual)
```

Output same as first now.

Comment: yes, I maked mistake to passing param2. Thanks your guid

Answer (score 0):

there must be a value error your code gives the same answer in both cases.

from file:

```
from typing import List,Dict,Tuple

def savings_account(client_to_accounts: Dict[Tuple[str, int],
                     List[List[float]]], valid_client: Tuple[str, int],
                       balance: float, interest: float)-> list:
   ''' Return the newest update of accounts added.'''

   key_list = client_to_accounts.keys()
   for i in key_list:
       if i == valid_client:
           last = len(client_to_accounts[i][0]) - 1
           client_to_accounts[i][0].insert(last,balance)
           client_to_accounts[i][1].insert(last,interest)

   return client_to_accounts[i]


param1 = {('Habib', 696969696): [[1.0, 10000.0], [2.0, 1.0]], ('Hendiye', 123456789): [[20000.0,
        -100.0], [1.0, 1.0]]}
param2 = (('Hendiye', 123456789),40.0, 2.0)
param3 =  40.0
param4 =   2.0

actual = savings_account(param1, param2, param3, param4)

print(actual)
```

**output :**

```
[[20000.0, 40.0, -100.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

and from shell

[image]

so, there is value error :)